# Chaining methods for adding items to a queue

Tags: php, design-patterns, laravel-4

I'm writing a log class which has several methods like `info`, `error` or `warning` to insert log entries into the database.

Until now every one of those methods directly made a db insert. This is not good performance whise when it comes to batch processing. I now want to solve this with creating a queue and only generate and fire one insert statement at the end of a task.

I'm now not sure if the following makes sense or is good practice. The way I would do it right now is chaining the methods to start and submit a queue like:

```php
Log::queue()->info('Just somehting')->warning('Strange stuff')->submit();
```

Or if I wan't to directly insert it:

```php
Log::info('Just something');
```

The class structure would for example look like this:

```php
class Log {
    protected $queue = array();
    protected $isQueued = false;

    public function queue() {
        $this->isQueued = true;

        return $this;
    }

    public function info() {
        if($this->isQueued) {
            //Add to queue
        } else {
            //Insert in db
        }

        return $this;
    }

    //All the other log types following...

    public function submit() {
        //Generate single insert statement from queue and insert it
    }
}
```

I'm using a Laravel facade hence the static calls.

Is there anything wrong with this design? I'm not sure because for example `Log::submit()` for itself would make absolutely no sense but would be possible. Does it even matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should probably do is drop the queue/commit methods, instead take incoming logs and store them in an array on the object, and then you can use a callback like `App::shutdown(function() {...})` to tell it to commit the in-memory log strings to the database once the application is done serving the request.

Also worth mentioning - If you're not restricted to using a SQL database, there are already several existing database Monolog handlers for Redis, Mongo and more. The underlying Monolog instance is available via `Log::getMonolog()`.

Comment: `App::shutdown` sounds pretty reasonable to me. I may implement it that way. I unfortunately was not able to find a log solution which fits my needs. I need to link the logs to specific entries in my sql db. Do you know anything that does that well?

Comment: The way you put it, it sounds like you're best off implementing it yourself.